# How can I get the NCSARequestLog to roll over hourly?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, access-log

Jetty provides the [NCSARequestLog](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Logging+Requests) to log the requests. But this seems to rollover on a daily basis by default.

Is there an option to have this rollover on an hourly basis?

Or is there a way to provide a custom log appender for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what exactly you mean with rollover, but I see two things worth trying:

1. Look at the `retainDays` setting, to define when old logs may be delted. [wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Request_Logs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Request_Logs)
2. Tyr to set the filename template to something that is hour-specific:

> ```
> <requestLog implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
>     <filename>target/yyyy_mm_dd_hh.request.log</filename>
>     <retainDays>10</retainDays>
>     <append>true</append>
>     <extended>true</extended>
>     <logTimeZone>GMT+1</logTimeZone>
> </requestLog>
> ```

Please feedback, if this works, since I didn't explicitly try it.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for getting back so late on this. I actually, went for a custom appender solution as I wanted some other custom changes to the access logs. But I think the second option should work. By rollover - I mean the rotation of the access log files by the hour.